# Recover Firefox bookmarks after Linux Mint 16 reinstallation

Tags: linux-mint, kde, firefox, bookmarks

I had Linux Mint 16 KDE installed alongside Xubuntu 13.10. I messed up partitions and had to reinstall Mint and both the OSs were booting fine after reinstallation. Now as expected all of my Firefox bookmarks were erased. Is there any way to recover those Firefox bookmarks?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your `.mozilla` directory from your old installations home directory? If yes, just copy that directory to your new home and change its ownership by a command like this:

```
~$ chown -R USER:root ~/.mozilla
```

And after this you will have all of your old Firefox configuration and also your old bookmarks.

Comment: I installed it on the same partition where I had installed it the last time

Comment: Did you removed old home directory? If yes there is no chance to retrieve that data again. Other possibility for you in such a situation is using Firefox's sync system or some backup software that upon your question I think you have not used neither of them!